# Computing intersection of infinite sets.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Need help in vetting my answers for the question #6 in CRM series book by MAA: Exploratory Examples for Real Analysis, By Joanne E. Snow, Kirk E. Weller. [image: here]

> Consider the following two collections of sets:
>   $$\{I_n = [0,\frac1n] \ : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
>   $$\{J_n = (0,\frac1n) \ : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
>
> (a) Compute $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$.
>   (b) Compute $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} J_n$.
>   (c) Can you explain the differences in the two answers using any of the terms introduced in this lab ([in chapter #1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=w5xE8mpZ4VoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false))?

(a) 
$I_1 = [0,1], I_2 = [0,\frac12], I_3 = [0,\frac13], I_4 = [0,\frac14], \cdots, I_{\infty} = [0,0] = 0$

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = [0,1]\cap[0,\frac12]\cap[0,\frac13]\cap[0,\frac14]\cdots \cap 0$

There need be found intersection of real points in all the given intervals, leading to finally single point $0$, which is the same as $I_{\infty}$.

(b) $J_1 = (0,1), J_2 = (0,\frac12), J_3 = (0,\frac13), J_4 = (0,\frac14), \cdots, J_{\infty} = (0,0)=\emptyset$ 
The last set is empty set ($\emptyset$), as .

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} J_n = (0,1)\cap(0,\frac12)\cap(0,\frac13)\cap(0,\frac14)\cdots \cap \emptyset $
$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} J_n = \emptyset $

In all non-null sets, the boundary of the intervals are not included.
The intersection of the sets is null set, as there is nothing in common of any set with $\emptyset$.

(c) Unable to find any term in chapter 1 of the book, that describes something related to empty set intersection with other sets leading to null set again. The chapter describes supremum, maximum, Upper bound, infimum, minimum, Lower bound.
This can be checked by the google-book link for the same.

Doubt:
1. Am I correct about taking the interval $I_\infty$, that represents a single point? 
 
2. Similarly, about $J_\infty$, which is empty set.

Comment: Yes, you have correctly determined both intersections.

Comment: @RobertShore Regarding part(c), am confused what the book wants as the relevant term. Definitely, there is something; but beyond my capability to find out.

Comment: I think it's as simple as noting that a closed interval contains its lower bound but an open interval does not.

Comment: I wouldn't write $[0,0]=0$ since the left side is a *set* while the right side is a *number*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like $I_\infty$ or $J_\infty$. It's not that your final answer is wrong, but these "last sets" in the collection are not defined in the question. You've invented them using your intuition. Your intuition happens to be consistent with the question, but you may not be so lucky next time.

(As an example of when your intuition might fail you, note that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \neq (0, 0) = \emptyset$.)

Instead, use your intuition to conjecture that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \{0\}$. To prove it, we do a classic subset proof. Start by supposing $x \in \{0\}$, i.e. $x = 0$. Then, show that $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$. By definition of intersection, this is equivalent to showing $x \in I_n$ for all $n$, which is true, since $0 \le 0 \le \frac{1}{n}$.

Conversely, suppose $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, which is to say that $x \in I_n$ for all $n$, and hence further that $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$. If we consider the constant sequence $x, x, x, \ldots$, then this means this constant sequence is squeezed between $0$ and $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, hence the constant sequence tends to $0$. But, the constant sequence tends to $x$ as well, hence by uniqueness of limits, $x = 0$. So, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n \subseteq \{0\}$.

Putting these two arguments together, we have proven that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \{0\}$.

Try something similar with the $J_i$s.

Comment: Could not understand how the example works, i.e.  $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \neq (0, 0) = \emptyset$. Please elaborate. Kindly vet my attempt for $J_i$. Suppose $x \in \emptyset$ show $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty J_n\implies x \in J_n \forall n$, i.e. vacuously true, as $\emptyset \in J_n$. Conversely, let $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty J_n \implies x \in J_n$. If consider constant sequence $x, x, x, \ldots$, this means this sequence is squeezed between .... Unable to add further.

Comment: @jiten For the $J_i$, the same argument works to show that $\bigcap J_i \subseteq \{0\}$: as $0 < x < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, by squeeze theorem, $x \to 0$, and hence $x = 0$. That is, every element of $\bigcap J_i$ belongs to $\{0\}$. The question is, which subset of $\{0\}$ is it? Is it the empty set, or is it $\{0\}$? Since $0$ is not an element of at least one of the $J_i$s (in fact, all of them), $0$ is certainly not in the intersection, so the intersection must be $\emptyset$.

Comment: @jiten As a "cute" alternative way, consider that $J_i \subseteq I_i \setminus \{0\}$ for all $i$, thus $$\bigcap J_i \subseteq \bigcap I_i \setminus \{0\} = \{0\} \setminus \{0\} = \emptyset.$$

Comment: @jiten As for the other example, call $K_n = (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$. Firstly, note that $0 \in K_n$ for all $n$, so $\{0\} \subseteq \bigcap K_n$. This already establishes that the intersection is non-empty. Try showing that the intersection is indeed equal to $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for completing the second part of proof using squeeze theorem. One question regarding the alternative proof: not clear if it is a standalone proof. If yes, then is 'another' formal approach proof. In the example, still unclear how $(-\frac{1}{\infty}, \frac{1}{\infty}) \ne (0,0) \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @jiten If you've shown that $\bigcap I_i = \{0\}$, then it shows that $\bigcap J_i \subseteq \emptyset$. With your note that $\emptyset \subseteq \bigcap J_i$, that completes the proof. So, it's not completely standalone. It just replaces the squeeze theorem bit from the $J_i$ proof.

Comment: @jiten As for your other question, leaving aside the fact that $\frac{1}{\infty}$ doesn't make sense, the interval $(0, 0)$ (which you might have called "$K_\infty$" if this were in the original question) is indeed equal to the empty set (since there is no $x$ such that $0 < x < 0$), but it is **not** in the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n$. The upper bound of $\infty$ is never attained in such intersections ($\infty$ is not a number; there is no $K_\infty$ defined in the problem). The notation means the set of elements common to $K_n$ for all (finite) $n$, which is $\{0\}$.